# Set difference is finite - transitive relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $A=P(\mathbb N)$. The relation $E$ is defined: $(X,Y) \in E$ iff $X \setminus Y$ and $Y \setminus X$ are finite.

I was given to prove this is an equivalence relation, however I had troubles proving the transitivity. Any hints?

Comment: $(X,Y) \in E$ & $(Y,Z) \in E$ then $(X,Z) \in E$. THIS MEANS: almost all elements of Z are in Y and almost all elements of Y are in X. SO almost all elements of Z are in X.   [almost all elements  =except finite elements]

Comment: I can see why it's right intuitively, but the what about formally?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to prove $X\setminus Z \subseteq (X\setminus Y) \cup (Y\setminus Z)$ first.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X,Y) \in E$ & $(Y,Z)∈E$. we prove $(X,Z) \in E$ (in one direction, the other will be similar):
if $c\in Z \setminus X$ then we have two possibility:
1) $c \in Y$ then $c\in Y\setminus X$, which is finite
2) $c\notin Y$ then $c\in Z\setminus Y$, which is finite